# Vertical spacing between sections

Tags: spacing, sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I would like to know how I can define the vertical space between:

- a previous section and the new section title;
- the new section title and the following text.

Now it looks like both space measure the same.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on the document class. Usually `\section` is defined `\@startsection` that is defined in the LaTeX kernel. The `article` class defines `\section` the following way:

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

[`source2e`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) documents the options for the 4th and 5th argument of `\@startsection` that controls the spaces before and after the section title:

> `\@startsection{⟨name⟩}{⟨level⟩}{⟨indent⟩}{⟨beforeskip⟩}{⟨afterskip⟩}{⟨style⟩}*[⟨altheading⟩]{⟨heading⟩}`
>
> **beforeskip:** Absolute value = skip to leave above the heading. If negative, then paragraph indent of text following heading is
>   suppressed.
>
> **afterskip:** if positive, then skip to leave below heading, else negative of skip to leave to right of run-in heading.

Example that redefines `\section` with doubled spaces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Section A}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Section B}
\lipsum[2]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\section}{%
\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-7ex \@plus -3ex \@minus -.4ex}%
  {4.6ex \@plus.4ex}%
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}%
}
\makeatother
\section{New Section C}
\lipsum[2]
\section{New Section D}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: How do you make the section header single-spaced if it spans multiple lines?

Comment: @YigitAlparslan This is a different topic for a new question (with example, since the answer will probably depend on the class).